# jos_users out of sync with jos_core_acl_aro on joomla database

Tags: php, sql, joomla

this is really something that is giving me headaches.
Last year i had this issue on my joomla site but i managed to sync those tables using a sql query that i dont have anymore.

I really tought that this got solved for good, but yesterday i just noticed that this tables are not sync anymore.
The jos_users table have 4967 users and the jos_core_acl_aro have 5135, wich is a big diference.

Im using joomla 1.5.22 and im using 2 components that i suspect it has something to do with this issue:
Regreminder ( Notify inactiv users and delete inactiv accounts for a specific time)
Unregister (Let the user delete their own account for good)

For now i would like to know a query to run in phpmyadmin so i can see wich data is missing in jos_users since jos_core_acl_aro have more data.
Something like comparing this 2 tables and check the data missing.
Ive been searching google for this but maybe im not im my lucky day..

Sincerely
Daniel Q.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know the table nor Joomla, so you have to fill in the gaps.

```
select a, b, c from jos_core_acl_aro
minus
select a, b, c from jos_users
```

a, b and c are the columns you want to see, which have to be in both tables (although they can have different names). Also together they should be unique in each table.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i dont know what is wrong but every sql query i run on phpmydam i get this error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select id, name from jos_users LIMIT 0, 30' at line 3. Damn

Comment: Any idea why im getting this error? any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: No idea what is wrong, but a general SQL debugging strategy: simplify the sql statement until it executes (replacing columns with *; removing out selects; removing where clauses). Then put the pieces back until it breaks. Look at that piece of code until it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks Jens, i really appreciate your advices but im afraid im not capable of doing what you say because i havent play to much with mysql and i can cnsider myself a beginer. i wanted to know what the diference betwen those 2 tales to try understand what users are missing and why they are missing, but i guess im gonna pass this and will sync those 2 tables one with another. Can you advice on what query should i run to sync ? Thanks

Comment: Hi Dani, just make it a new question. Include the full table definition. And post a link to the question here.